# How to count previous siblings in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

**Summary:**

I'm using TestCafe and I know it's not a difficult question which I'm asking (JQuery has a solution for this). I'm looking for a solution in TestCafe.

[image]

**Question:**

I need to know how many (count in integer) previous siblings (`button`) exists from the highlighted blue. In my case the answer should be 4.

**What I've done so far**

As per the screenshot, I'm in the element index 4 (but I don't know). I've used following selector to reach the element:

`Selector('div.group-name').withExactText('f61ck72g83m')`

Now, to count the previous sibling I tried this:

`Selector('div.group-name').withExactText('f61ck72g83m').parent('button.group-info').prevSibling('button').count`

and this returns a promise which I don't want:
`ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }`

Answer (score 2):

I missed `await` before calling the element. Silly question indeed.